# How many attacks does this dragon have per round?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, multiattack

I created a dragon for my group and am interested about its attacks during a fight. The [detailed statblock can be found here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon/chromatic-blue/young-blue-dragon).

Am I right that the dragon has two attacks per round, [since his BAB is higher than 5 and smaller than 11](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attack-Bonus)?
So - as a standard action - can he attack in one round with his bite and with both claws, or just his two claws?

Is he able to cast ghost sound and attack with both wings in the same round as a standard action?

When using a full round action, how many attacks can he do?

As you can see, I'm quite confused about the number of attacks per round (for a standard action or for a full round action)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Natural attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attack) work completely different than attacks with manufactured weapons. You get one attack per "natural weapon", but you do not get iterative attacks for high BAB.

> [...] You do not receive additional natural attacks for a high base attack bonus. Instead, you receive additional attack rolls for multiple limb and body parts capable of making the attack (as noted by the race or ability that grants the attacks). [...]

In your case, the dragon can, as a full-round action do all the attacks listed under

> **Melee** bite +15 (2d6+7), 2 claws +14 (1d8+5), 2 wings +12 (1d6+2), tail slap +12 (1d8+7)

Or any one of them as a standard action. That means 1 bite, 1 claw, 1 wing or 1 tail slap, at the bonuses and damage listed above.

Bite and claws are primary natural attacks, which means they are made at full BAB+Str (+1 for the bite because of of weapon focus). The wings and the tail slap are secondary natural attacks, which means they are made at -2, due to the [multiattack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/multiattack-combat) feat the dragon has.

Using the ghost sound SLA is a standard action in and of itself, so it can't be combined with any attack that round.

Comment: so full-round is clear to me. (boy, is this beast powerful!) and for standard action that would mean any of the comma-separated attacks? so also the 2 claws attacks which would mean +14/+14 (1d8+5) ?

Comment: @mawimawi no - as a standard action your dragon can make a *single* claw attack - it's almost unheard of to get more than a single attack as a standard action in PF

Comment: @mawimawi GoBLin is correct, I have edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: Ahh, found the correct page. It's in Combat rather than universal monster...

Comment: Note that a dragon's full attack can be incredibly fatal to even high level PCs.  Playing a dragon smart - increasing his own survivability with techniques like strafing with breath weapons and using spells from a high hover - also increases the PCs' survivability as well, because he's not landing in the middle of the melee and dropping full attacks.  If he's cornered in his lair, though...  well, animals get dangerous when cornered.  Let that full-attack go and the survivors will find someplace besides melee range to be.

Comment: Does this also apply to player characters who have natural weapons such as a bite or claw attack?

Comment: @Sandwich Yes. Note that all natural attacks are secondary when used in combination with manufactured weapons (last paragraph of "Natural Weapons" (see first link))